# Getting error while running the Jenkins job for Cypress automation test : The cypress npm package is installed, but the Cypress binary is missing

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, automation, cypress

I am getting the below error while running the jenkins job which i have integrated for cypress test cases.

```
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\Users\Gaurav\CypressAutomation
[CypressAutomation] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins16040665516745242535.bat

C:\Users\Gaurav\CypressAutomation>npm install   && npm run "test" 

up to date, audited 651 packages in 5s

65 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

> cypressautomation@1.0.0 test
> node_modules\.bin\cypress run

The cypress npm package is installed, but the Cypress binary is missing.

We expected the binary to be installed here: C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\11.2.0\Cypress\Cypress.exe

Reasons it may be missing:

- You're caching 'node_modules' but are not caching this path: C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache
- You ran 'npm install' at an earlier build step but did not persist: C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache

Properly caching the binary will fix this error and avoid downloading and unzipping Cypress.

Alternatively, you can run 'cypress install' to download the binary again.

https://on.cypress.io/not-installed-ci-error

----------

Platform: win32-x64 (10.0.19043)
Cypress Version: 11.2.0
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
[htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
[htmlpublisher] Archiving at BUILD level C:\Users\Gaurav\CypressAutomation\cypress\reports\html to C:\Users\Gaurav\.jenkins\jobs\CypressAutomation\builds\18\htmlreports\Cypress_20Report
ERROR: Specified HTML directory 'C:\Users\Gaurav\CypressAutomation\cypress\reports\html' does not exist.
Finished: FAILURE
```

Please find the configuartion

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is your npm config (`.npmrc` file) set with `ignore-scripts` https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/config#ignore-scripts. If you add `npm config ls` to your pipeline, you can view everything the npm config before running npm install.

Answer (score 0):

for CI you can use the `npm ci` command which designed for this purpose.
Here the doc: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-ci